# How to remain or reconnect the attribute of the "from" and "to" point in network analysis

Tags: qgis-network-analysis

I am doing a network distance analysis from layer 1 to layer 2. I used GRASS/v.net.distance. I have one problem with the outcome is that I cannot link back the result with the original point layer.

Below is the screenshot of the two attribute tables, table (1) is the attribute table of the "from" layer and table (2) is the result. I assume that column "cat" is the starting point, it refers to the point in table (1) but I can't link them together.

[image]

I hope my question is clear...